# laravel 5: soft delete

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, eloquent

I added `deleted_at` filed in tables and the default value is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`(which is must in mysql),now using `User::first()` can not get the value when `deleted_at  = 0000-00-00 00:00:00`. any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you add the column?

If you use Laravels `Schema` within a migrations there is a `softDeletes()` column which defaults to `null` (you could also do this in your database directly of course).

Comment: Thanks, I think timestamp must be set 0 as default value in mysql.

Answer (score 4):

When you call the delete method on the model, the `deleted_at` column will be set to the `current date and time`. And, when querying a `model` that uses `soft deletes`, **the soft `deleted` models will automatically be excluded from all query results**.

To make your code working set `deleted_at` field to `null`.

To delete the model you can use below logic

```
$deletedRows = App\Flight::where('active', 0)->delete();
```

Reference http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#soft-deleting

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the value of record has `deleted_at` = `NULL` otherwise row cannot be retrieved. If you want to get the desired row, just set the `deleted_at = NULL`

You should use softDelete like the code below, it will automatically create proper column with proper default value.

```
Schema::table('table_name', function(Blueprint $table)
{
   $table->softDeletes();
});
```